# Selenium script getting error 'value cannot be null parameter: source' after setting password textbox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting an error "Value cannot be null,parameter name: s" after setting password through selenium script and clicking submit button.

Please help me on this, Thanks

Am using the below code for setting password

```
var passwordtxt=driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtpassword"));
var JSexecutor= (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
JSexecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])",passwordtxt,"mypassword");
```

Comment: Why not `Sendkeys()`?

Comment: You could use sendKeys(), can you share the HTML source?
This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176498/how-to-enter-password-using-selenium-webdriver-if-the-password-style-is-display

Comment: when I am using SendKeys, am getting an error " Element cannot be interacted with via the keyboard because it is not diplayed". But element is visible in the page.

Comment: then you are probably sending the value to the wrong element.  If you can share the relevant section of HTML source, we could confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you provided, it sounds like the item `passwordtxt` doesn't exist on the page. `Value cannot be null` is referring to the element you pass into `ExecuteScript`, which is `passwordtxt` in this case.

To solve this problem, you will need to change the way you are finding `passwordtxt`. If you post some more HTML from your page's source, we can help you determine the correct selector to use.